# Beta Release for a specific group of users on live site

Tags: web, release, release-management, beta

We have website/portal currently successfully running live. There was a module called Lets say "A". Which is already developed.

Client asked to add some more tremendous amount of features and updates to that module.

Now we need to give beta release of this new development to specific group of users and rest of the users will have same old application.

Can anyone suggest a better and a kind of good standard approach to give beta releases on Live Site.

Thanks